# C++ Syntax: Add new vector to a list

Tags: c++, syntax-error

Ok, so this is a bit complicated and my syntax memory sucks...

I have a list which holds vectors of objects called "Plane".

Here:

```
std::list<std::vector<Plane>> possible_planes;
```

Plane is a class I made.
What I am trying to do now is add new entries to that.
So something like this:

```
possible_planes.push_back(std::vector<Plane> new Plane(boundRect[i].area(), center[i]));
```

And here is where I fail to get the syntax right. What does the correct syntax look like?

Comment: Are you sure you need a two-dimensional container here? Your code and variable name suggest otherwise. That said, `possible_planes` contains vectors, so add a vector to it. Then add Planes to the *vector* (not to the *list* of vectors).

Comment: That would not be the place to be declaring that variable, not should the word `new` appear anywhere in this code.

Comment: Yes I need a 2D container. I think my variables suggest that there have to be multiple list entries --> planes. There are many planes of the same kind. Thats why there is a vector which holds the ones which belong together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is declaring a variable in the middle of an expression, as well as dynamically allocating when it should not be. Try this:

```
possible_planes.push_back(std::vector<Plane>());
possible_planes.back().push_back(Plane(boundRect[i].area(), center[i]));
```

Note, this could be reduced even more if I knew you were using a C++11 compliant toolchain.

Comment: This seems right thanks. I thought I had to use new but apparently the constructor (?) does that for me already?

Comment: @user2175762 The [new operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) allocates new memory on the heap and returns a pointer to that location. The constructor just allocates memory on the stack. Let the compiler do the work for you.

Comment: Hum, but at the compile time I do not know how many instances I will have. Thats why I went with the new operator..

Comment: @user2175762 the vector will handle the allocation of your Plane for you, just as the list does when you're pushing a new vector on to it. There's a *lot* going on behind the scenes with those two lines.

Comment: Thanks, yea there is a lot going on. The thing is I thought that I need to know the size for the list allocation, thats why I tried to create the list entry with my parameters. But now I think it only holds some kind of pointer, so it does not really matter how big that vector actually is. Am I correct?

Comment: I have a new problem. No I want to access members from my "Plane" class. possible_planes[i].end().setKeypoints(keypoints); This won't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @user2175762 `end()` is not the correct member. use `back()` to access the last item in a list of at-least-one item.

Comment: Thanks again. But I am using iterators now. Seems way easier. When I write `possible_planes[i].` it does not find any members. So I do not know how to select one specific list entry. `at()` does not exit either...

Comment: @user2175762 then check your indexing, because if there are N items in the vector, they should be indexible via 0..(N.1).

Answer (score 2):

1. first create new vector, then add the plane

```cpp
  possible_planes.push_back(std::vector<Plane>());
  possible_planes.back().push_back(Plane(boundRect[i].area(), center[i]));
```

2. have a function like this one

```cpp
  std::vector<Plane> createNewPlaneVector(Plane& plane) {
    std::vector<Plane> result;
    result.push_back(plane);
    return result;
  }
```

then you can add then new vector in one line

```cpp
  possible_planes.push_back(createNewPlaneVector(Plane(boundRect[i].area(), center[i])));
```

If you are using C++11 then this gets simpler:

```cpp
possible_planes.push_back(std::vector<Plane>() { Plane(boundRect[i].area(), center[i]) } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try doing it with multiple lines and variables, like this:

```
vector<Plane> newPlane; // Vector you add to list later
Plane myPlane; // Your object
// Do what you want with your Plane object
newPlane.push_back(myPlane); // Insert your object to vector
possible_planes.push_back(newPlane); // Insert vector to list
```